# Error related to database connection in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, database-connection

I am stuck into a error. I tried to do different thing but couldn't solve the problem.

This is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied
```

The website on which I am getting this error is `pickprogress.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is telling you that your database configuration is wrong. You should try to edit the `app/config/databases.php` (or similar) file.

Comment: No then the exception would be different if there is configuration error. In this link `http://blog.kosmokaryote.org/2014/03/technology-apache-php-mysql-pdo.html`i came to know about another person who had the same problem but he resolved it. But don't know how he do that. If you understand this issue please help me then.

Comment: What about the `host` parameter in your config file ? If it is correct, then it is probably a real permission issue and you should look at other applications that may have strict permission requirements.

Comment: yup it's permission know i dont know how to solve it :'(